# Use stat to get most recently modified directory

Tags: c, stat

This is proving to be incredibly difficult.  I want to use `stat` to get the name of the most recently modified directory.  I've researched `stat` quite a bit, but I honestly don't really understand how to use it, so I don't really have any code to show.

How can I get the most recently modified directory in C using `stat`?

Comment: How to use stat: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/240418/find-latest-files
In order to execute this command in c use execl.

Comment: How is your list of directories constructed?  There'll be a an issue with time of check for each directory; if you have a thousand directories, you might find a modification time, t1, for the first directory, and you might find a modification time tN on the Nth directory with t1 < tN, but between the time you evaluate t1 and finish evaluating the thousand directories, the first directory might have been modified, leaving it as the most recently modified directory.  But there's no easy way to avoid that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are familiar with listing all files (and extract out directories) from a given directory [ If not read up on opendir/ readdir ].The algorithm will not be accurate because a directory can get touched after its time stamp was checked but assuming that's not a concern, here is something that you might be doing

```
    DIR *dirp = opendir(".");
    struct stat dStat;
    time_t latest = 0;
    while ((dp = readdir(dirp)) != NULL) {
            memset(&dStat, 0, sizeof(dStat));
            if (stat(dp->d_name, &dStat) < 0) {
                    printf("Error getting info on file\n");
                    continue;
            }
            // If not a directory skip 
            if ((dStat.st_mode & S_IFDIR) != S_IFDIR) {
                    continue;
            }
            // check with the latest timestamp
            if (dStat.st_mtime > latest) {
                    // On finding a more recent file switch that to latest
                    strcpy(dName, dp->d_name);
                    latest = fStat.st_mtime;
            }
    }
    closedir(dirp);
    printf("Most recently touched directory %s\n", dName);
```